# How to edit a variable in a class array

Tags: c#, arrays

Not sure how to phrase title so sorry for poor wording but if I have something like this

```
public class Item
{ 
     public string itemName;
     public double itemPrice;
     public double shipping;
     public double tax = 0.12;
     public double total;
}
```

Then I proceeded to declare an array

```
Item[] item = new Item[100]
```

I feel like this is a bad way to create an array like this but the problem here is an arbitrary sized array so I know for sure it will be under 100 but the items will keep getting added on.

How can I now edit item[0]'s itemPrice?

I tried using:

```
item[0].itemPrice = 34;
```

but with no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you initialized each of the item objects in the array?

Comment: On a side-note you might want to read up on how to use constructors and getter/setter methods.

Comment: If it helped you, you could accept the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Item[] item = new Item[100];`, you just allocate memory for your collection, but you need to initialize each object in this array too.

```
Item[] item = new Item[100];
item[0] = new Item();
item[0].itemName = "1";
```

Comment: Thanks i didn't initialize each item.

Comment: you will need a loop to initialize each item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the item(s) first

```
item[0] = new Item();
item[0].itemprice = 34;
```

PS you should make those public members properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = new List<Item>();
item.Add(new Item())
items.First().ItemName = "Foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `List<Item>` instead of an array. `List<T>` automatically extends itself when you add items to it.

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
Item myItem = new Item();
list.Add(myItem);

list[0].itemPrice = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an array of `Item`, you're creating the array, but no class instances; `item[0]` will be `null`.

An easy way to create an arbitary number of instances is using `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select (_ => new Item()).ToList();
```

This creates a list of 20 `Item` instances (you could also create an array by calling `ToArray` instead of `ToList`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize each item in the array.
Assuming you have a suitable constructor...

```
Item[] item = new Item[100]

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    item[i] = new item();
}

item[0].itemPrice = 34;
```